# How to calculate modulus of the form (a*b)%c?

Tags: c++, overflow, modulus

How to calculate modulus of the form (a*b)%c?

i want to calculate modulus of multiplication of two int numbers where they are almost in the stage of overflow...

here c is also int

Answer (score 15):

```
(a * b) % c == ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c
```

Comment: +1 Just commented this, but the lack of coffee meant I was not sure. ;)

Comment: If a <= b < c, a % c and b % c will do nothing, so we could still get an overflow.

Answer (score 7):

What about `((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`? Depending on your architecture this could be faster or slower than casting to a bigger type.

Comment: If a <= b < c, a % c and b % c will do nothing, so we could still get an overflow.

Answer (score 5):

You may cast `a` and `c` to `long long`, so the multiplication won't overflow.

```
((long long)a * (long long)b) % c
```

Comment: i need something optimized method

Comment: I don't think you would find a faster solution. On x86 machines, the result of 32 bit multiplication is always 64-bit. This way you just notify the compiler to use 64-bit result.

Comment: long long is not always bigger than int (especially on modern machines)