# Multiply two overflowing integers modulo a third

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Given three integers, `a`, `b`and `c` with `a,b <= c < INT_MAX` I need to compute `(a * b) % c` but `a * b` can overflow if the values are too large, which gives the wrong result.

Is there a way to compute this directly through bithacks, i.e. without using a type that won't overflow for the values in question?

Comment: Must be going to the same class as Ivella: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857702/specific-modular-multiplication-algorithm

Comment: No, I just reduce my problems until they sound like homework… Katabusa seems quite involved, I was hoping there was some obvious bit-hacking I missed (like the `(a % c) * (b % c) % c` mentioned in the link, which doesn't apply to my problem though…)

Comment: @MatsPetersson If a < c then a % c == a

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow: a\*a mod n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076011/overflow-aa-mod-n) (Specifically, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10076069/129570) there).  This is for squaring, but can trivially be adapted for arbitrary multiplication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8733178/995714

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Karatsuba's algorithm is not really needed here. It is enough to split your operands just once.

Let's say, for simplicity's sake, that your numbers are 64-bit unsigned integers. Let k=2^32. Then

```
a=a1+k*a2
b=b1+k*b2
(a1+k*a2)*(b1+k*b2) % c = 
   a1*b1 % c + k*a1*b2 % c + k*a2*b1 % c + k*k*a2*b2 % c
```

Now `a1*b1 % c` can be computed immediately, the rest could be computed by alternately performing `x <<= 1` and `x %= c` 32 or 64 times (since (u*v)%c=((u%c)*v)%c). This could ostensibly overflow if `c >= 2^63`. However, the nice thing is that this pair of operations need not be performed literally. Either `x < c/2` and then you only need a shift (and there's no overflow), or `x >= c/2` and

```
2*x % c = 2*x - c = x - (c-x).
```

(and there's no overflow again).

Answer (score 0):

Several of the major compilers offer a 128-bit integer type, with which you can do this computation without overflow.