# How to compute this modulus when there is an integer overflow

Tags: math, numbers, modulo

```
(10^{17}-1)*(10^{17}-1) mod 10^{18}
```

I am solving a programming problem and I hold my integers in 64 bit long long integers. Above is a particular case I am unable to solve. (ab)mod m = (a mod m)*(b mod m) mod m, doesn't hold here as  (a mod m)*(b mod m) would still overflow a 64 bit integer. How do I solve this? I took 17th power only as an example. The problem holds even for all the integers in the range (10^{10}, 10^{18}-1).

Edit: I am using C++ for solving this problem. This problem can be solved without using a library for handling big integers.

Comment: Looks like you might need to use a library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/handling-large-numbers-in-c unless you want the experience of writing one yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857702/specific-modular-multiplication-algorithm (which has an accepted answer).

Comment: You said `17` in the exponent is just an example. Do you need a solution for this particular structure of the expression or in general for large integer mod operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the identity you quoted, you just need another similar identity: `(a+b) mod m = (a mod m) + (b mod m)`.

The goal is to multiply `x*y mod m` without any intermediate values exceeding the overflow limit (in this case 2^64), where `x` is starting less than `m` (if it isn't, reduce it mod `m`), `y` is possibly larger than `m`, and `x*y` can potentially overflow. We can do this if `m` is less than half of the overflow limit.

A solution is simple: Just perform basic multiplication bit-by-bit for `x*y` and do every step modulo `m`.

Start with `x` and `y` less than `m` (if either isn't, reduce it first). Write `y` in the form `a_0 * 2^0 + a_1 * 2^1 + a_2 * 2^2` + ... , where `a_n` is either 0 or 1 (indicating the term is present or not). (Aka, write `y` in binary form.) Now we have:

```
x * (a_0 * 2^0 + a_1 * 2^1 + a_2 * 2^2 + ...) mod m
```

Distribute `x` over each of the terms of `y`:

```
(x * a_0 * 2^0) + (x * a_1 * 2^1) + (x * a_2 * 2^2) + ... mod m
```

Then use the original multiplication identity: For each term above, multiply `x` by 2 mod `m` until you reach the desired power of 2 for that term. (Since `x < m` and `2 * m < 2^64`, then `2 * x < 2^64`, so we can multiply by 2 without overflowing.) When you are done, add the result for each term mod `m` (you can keep a running sum as you go).

None of those operations will exceed 2^64 and thus will not overflow. This will work for any value of `m` less than 2^64 / 2 = 2^63 and any integers `x` and `y` less than `m`.

This is not necessarily the fastest way to do it, feel free to find something more efficient. For starters, the smaller `m` is compared to the overflow limit, the bigger the radix for the terms we can rewrite `y` as.